# How to extract html with beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The html looks like this:

```
<td class='Thistd'><a ><img /></a>Here is some text.</td>
```

I only want to get the string in the `<td>`. I don't need `<a>...</a>`.
How can I do that?

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<td class='Thistd'><a><img /></a>Here is some text.</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tds = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'Thistd'})
for td in tds:
    print td
    print '============='
```

What I get is `<td class='Thistd'><a ><img /></a>Here is some text.</td>`

But I just need `Here is some text.`

Comment: what is the difference between what you got and what you want

Comment: sorry,there are some wrongs, fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`td.getText()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get the pure text from your element.

**i.e.)**

```
for td in tds:
    print td.getText()
    print '============='
```

**output:**

```
Here is some text.
=============
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can remove the `<a>` element then print the left.`.extract` method removes that particular tag from available bs4 object

**i.e.)**

```
for td in tds:
    td.a.extract()
    print td
```

**output:**

```
<td class="Thistd">Here is some<b>here is a b tag </b></td>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Vignesh, for your enhancement to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<td class='Thistd'><a ><img /></a>Here is some text.</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tds = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'Thistd'})
for td in tds:
    print td.text#the only change you need to do
    print '============='
```

**Output:**

```
Here is some text.
=============
```

**Note:**

the `.text` is used to get only the text attribute of the given bs4 object in this case it is `td` tag .For more information look it to the [official site](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: OK.tks, but if the html code was like this"<td class='Thistd'><a ><img /></a>Here is some<b>here is a b tag </br> and a br tag</b> text.</td>"  How could we get "Here is some<b>here is a b tag </br> and a br tag</b> text."?

Comment: so you also want to get the tags

Comment: @jianbingMa flicker has added the answers